# How do you set a Dart IO Process to use an existing Stream for its stdin?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I'm creating a Process using Process.start and am a bit stuck with the stdin getter. Ideally, I've got a StreamController set up elsewhere, whose stream of Strings I'd like to pass into stdin. But there aren't too many sophisticated examples for interacting with Process.stdin, so I'm not sure how to do anything more than a writeln to stdin.

So I've got something like this, that I can add String messages to:

```dart
  StreamController<String> processInput = new StreamController<String>.broadcast();
```

And I want to do something like this:

```dart
  Process.start(executable, args, workingDirectory: dir.path, runInShell: true).then((Process process) {
process.stdout
  .transform(UTF8.decoder)
  .listen((data) {
    s.add('[[CONSOLE_OUTPUT]]' + data);
  });
process.stdin.addStream(input.stream);
});
```

I realize that `addStream()` wants `Stream<List<int>>`, though I'm not sure why that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stdin` object is an `IOSink`, so it has a `write` method for strings. That will default to UTF-8 encoding the string. 
So, instead of

```dart
process.stdin.addStream(input.stream)
```

you can do

```dart
IOSink stdin = process.stdin;
input.stream.listen(stdin.write, onDone: stdin.close);
```

You may want some error handling, possibly flushing stdin between writes, so maybe:

```dart
input.stream.listen(
    (String data) {
      stdin.write(data);
      stdin.flush();
    }, 
    onError: myErrorHandler,
    onDone: stdin.close);
```

Alternatively you can do the UTF-8 encoding manually, to get the stream of list of integers that `addStream` expects:

```dart
process.stdin.addStream(input.stream.transform(UTF8.encoder))
```

The reason why `stdin` expects a `List<int>` is that process communication is, at its core, just bytes. Sending text requires the sender and the receiver to pre-agree on an encoding, so they can interpret the bytes the same way.

Comment: The send/receive understanding on an encoding method makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```dart
process.stdin.addStream(UTF8.encoder.bind(input.stream));
```